# Windows print screen when using Boot Camp

Tags: keyboard, windows, bootcamp

I have bootcamp installed on my Mac, and when on Windows, I need to frequently capture screens using windows shortcuts such as Print Screen.

Using virtualization is not an option, since I need to run a virtualized environment within Windows already.

On the Mac keyboard (I have a MacBook Pro, and an external think aluminum keyboard), there isn't a print screen key. Is there any equivalent when using a mac keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these instructions in order to map the F13-F15 keys on an Apple keyboard to the functions, Print Screen, Scroll Lock, and Break commonly found on PC keyboards:

1. On your PC, copy the following lines into a text file.

REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,46,E0,5F,00,46,00,5E,00,37,E0,5D,00,00,00,00,00

1. Rename the text file remap.reg
2. Double click on the file remap.reg and answer yes to the question about adding the information to the registry
3. Reboot

Function keys are now remapped to their PC equivalents

Source: [MacWindows.com](http://www.macwindows.com/keytips.html#012203)

Comment: You should mention that this answer was copied and pasted from [MacWindows.com](http://www.macwindows.com/keytips.html#012203).

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1167) at Apple's KB includes the mapping of Windows keys to each of their keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows (with Boot Camp software installed) you can press <kbd>F13</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to take a screenshot.